# Permission denied on deploying react web app on azure

Tags: azure, github, npm, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I am deploying a react web app on azure by creating a workflow on github.
Now after committing changes it shows an error on creating build as:
[image]

The same error occured when I was deploying it using surge.sh
Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Mark's response. Try the following steps to further narrow-down the issue:

-Please check if there is a .deployment file in the root of the repository, and provide this file if present, along with the deploy._ file if present (deploy.cmd, deploy.sh, deploy.ps1).

-Just to isolate, test the deployment directly from your local Git repository to a new App Service.

--If a .deployment and **deploy.sh** file are included in the root directory of the app code, Kudu will use the legacy build to run the commands specified in the **deploy.sh** script.

--Just to highlight on this, Kudu is the engine behind Git deployments on both Windows and Linux. By default, App service uses Oryx to build/install and Kudu will determine type of stack is used and creates a generic **deploy.sh** script to install the packages.

-App Service sets the environment variable `PORT` in the Node.js container, and forwards the incoming requests to your container at that port number.  your app should listen to that port using `process.env.PORT`

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
```

1.Add a start-up script:  **Add the PM2 configuration file or your script file**

2.Go to Azure Configuration>**General Settings**

If your build folder is at the root of the project:

**Start up command**: `pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa`

Certain web frameworks may use **custom startup scripts** when running in **production mode**.
Refer this doc [Customize build automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/configure-language-nodejs?pivots=platform-linux#customize-build-automation) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem related to the Node.js module in your repository. Therefore, I suggest you do the following

Part 1: Reinstall the Node module

1. yarn uninstall
2. yarn install

Part 2: Redeploy the project via GitHub Action

Part 3: Deploy the React app directly from Azure Portal